# Error in getting all contacts

Tags: java, android, basic4android

i work basic4android and i want to run a java code with JavaObject in it.

i want to get all contacts. my java code is :

```
    #if java
import android.content.*;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public String getall()
{
String res="";
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
  String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
  String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
  res = res + name + " , " + phoneNumber + "\n";

}
phones.close();
        return res;

}
#end if
```

app runs but i get an error : java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

please help me. thanks.

Comment: do you give your app permissions to read the contacts?

Comment: tnx my friend , i added AddManifestText(<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>) it works great.

Comment: but now some of my phone numbers show left to right and some of them is right to left , they are not able to read  . i.e a number 30008127 shows : 27-081-300

Comment: if a number doesn't have a dash it  shows right but if my number is saved with dash in contacts such as 300-081-27 , it will show as wrong : 27-081-300 . how can i solve this ???

Comment: I shuld know more about how you show, or store contacts in your app ... but to fit SO rules, for thi you should ask a new  question

Comment: i writed returned string to a file and also showed in msgbox but in both,order of showing some numbers that contains dash , is wrong !!!

Comment: i solved with : phoneNumber.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", "") to remove dashes !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

To your's AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: yeah , tnx , i added this.but now my problem is some of my phone numbers doesn't appear in right order !

Comment: what you mean by wrong order? sorry for late answer.